# Including the Foreign Key Id in Code First to save queries?

Tags: database, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code First.

Right now my model looks the following:

```
public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

The thing is, I got a list of cities.
I need to lookup the region of each city (I have a local list of regions as well).

Now, I suppose I could do the following:

```
    foreach (var c in cities)
    {
        if (regions.Any(x => x.Id == c.Region.Id))
    }
```

Here I will have to look up a region from the database for each city (lazy loading).
However, I only need the Id of the region, therefore it seems wasteful to me to look up the region row at every loop.

If I changed my City model to be the following:

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Region")]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

I could do the following instead:

```
foreach (var c in cities)
    {
        if (regions.Any(x => x.Id == c.RegionId)) //no region lookup at Im using the foreign id key
    }
```

Is this correct? I mean it will save me a query for every city right?

If so, is there any reason NOT to include the foreign id keys in the model when doing Code First at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct? I mean it will save me a query for every city right?

It will save a join to the Regions table. You have to check it out with the SQL Profiler! For example:

List of cities with Id City1, City2 (Region not loaded City1= has RegionId 5)
Now you are looking for any City has a Region with Id 5.

```
// EF does not have to join the tables because you have the RegionId
if (myDbContext.Cities.Any(c => c.RegionId == 5))
{
}
```

> If so, is there any reason NOT to include the foreign id keys in the
>   model when doing Code First at all?

No for me this it is a good practice! Just keep it consistent and do it for all relationships of the type 1..n/1..0or1.